# How canl I set condition in layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, ifconfig

I have layout file have block like this

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Partsoto\CategoryCustom\Block\Search" name="category.custom.replacement.search" before="-"  template="Partsoto_CategoryCustom::replacement_sidebar.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I want to set condition  if querystring =  `"replacement?code=AAA"`

show container name = "sidebar.additional" .

Is it possible?

Comment: Can please put  your  condition properly, it the condition is `?code=AAA`

Comment: only donot want to show container   name `sidebar.additional`?

Comment: This is page for show  brand  .   only  'AAA' brand  show container name sidebar.additional .  rest of brands page  don't  show this sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

*You have to create a **module/extension** for your requirement.*

In magento2, the best way to **remove a container that  via layout**

> `<referenceContainer name="{Containername}" remove="true"/>`

So, lets create a handle which will **create a layout handler** like *default.xml catalog_product_view.xml,catalog_product_view.xml etc* using  **event** `layout_load_before` [`(Event/Observer)`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).

**Using  that custom handle files remove the `sidebar.additional`**

In your case, create a handle **which will only create** when you  **have a query** ?`code=AAA` and the query param **`code`** is not equal `AAA`.

Create `events.xml` at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend/`

and code  like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="renerate_custom_handle" instance="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Observer\CreateNewHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer file `CreateNewHandler.php` should be located at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Observer`

```
   <?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CreateNewHandler implements  ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();



       $lets= (isset($_GET['code'])&& $_GET['code'] !='AAA' && strlen($_GET['code'])> 0 )
        ?'sidebar_remove_brand': null ;
        if($lets != null){
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($lets);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Last create a layout file `sidebar_remove_brand.xml` at  `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <!--
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    -->
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="false" />
</body>
</page>
```